# Error to call a method in Doctrine, Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I don't understand why I get the following error in my Symfony2 project:
Error: Call to a member function getQueryId() on a non-object

Here are my codes:

Bibliorepository:

```
<?php

namespace Xxxx\XxxxxBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * BiblioRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class BiblioRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function wantAuthor($author)
      {

        $query = $this->_em->createQuery('SELECT b FROM XxxxBundle:Biblio b WHERE b.author = :author');
        $query->setParameter('author', $author);

        $result_author = $query->getResult();

      return $result_author;

    }
}
```

The getter:

```
    /**
     * Get queryId
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getQueryId()
    {
        return $this->queryId;
    }
}
```

And the controller:

```
$author = $this->getUser()->getId();

        $repository = $this

    ->getDoctrine()

    ->getManager()

    ->getRepository('XxxxBundle:Biblio');

  $resultBiblio = $repository->wantAuthor($author);
  $resultBiblio->getQueryId();
  foreach ($resultBiblio as $id_query) {

    $repository = $this

    ->getDoctrine()

    ->getManager()

    ->getRepository('XxXxBundle:Query');

    $resultQuery = $repository->wantQuery($id_query);
    $titles = $resultQuery->getQuery();

    }




        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl("fos_user_profile_show"));
```

Thank you very much for your help ;)

Comment: The error states that you are calling a `getContent` method on a non object, I do not see any calls to `getContent` in the code you have provided. Can you check in the error logs for the file and line number that the error is occurring and provide the relevant code.

Comment: Have you tried googling? I can see multiple reports on when that msg is displayed. (e.g. if you named the database connection and the eCart object the same.)

Comment: It might be a cache or a twig-template problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902991/symfony2-fatal-error-every-time-i-change-a-twig-file   This articel states that someone had a view with file-extension of *.twig.twig after renaming it *.html.twig it worked.

Comment: Sorry I updated my post, I made a mistake, it is not about getContent() but about getQueryId()

Comment: Did you try to pass a whole $author object to wantAuthor? Not just it's ID

Comment: How do I do that? I need to know what is the current user logged and it is why I dit a $author = $this->getUser()->getId();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$resultBiblio is an array with object. You invoke a method on array and this causes error.

You can invoke this method in foreach like

```
  foreach ($resultBilbo as $singleResult){
   $singleResult->getQueryId();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Var dump results `wantAuthor($author)` method and make sure you're getting the `Author` object in return. I bet you're not getting one.

Comment: Yes I got :  private 'author' => string '1' (length=1)

Comment: can you post the whole var dump?

Comment: just like I said you've got an array of objects. run array in `foreach` and then access `getQueryId`.